# Un-duplicate my question that was posted on U&L & Security SE sites?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting, exact-duplicates

I asked a question on U&L ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148531/79818 ) and latter on Security ( https://security.stackexchange.com/q/69189/57225 ) where I received an answer (sort of).

How can I merge the two question ? or do I simply need to answer myself in both forum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On U&L we frown upon [cross posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and in our [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it is is explicitly mentioned. That your post has not been closed yet is just because until now nobody noticed and voted to close.

Please remove the question on this site, if someone encounters a problem similar to yours, and searches for it on google, (s)he will find the answer on Security.
Doing so automatically unduplicates your question and solves the problem of multiple updates.

Comment: U&L question deleted.

Comment: @Archemar thank you