# fuzzing of cross posting policy

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

Sorry if this sounds a bit like an often asked question:

A recent [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229541/view-full-commands-in-ps-output) about `ps` which was already answered in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159860/viewing-full-output-of-ps-command) , according to comment, Cross posting was OK.

When I cross posted ([U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148531/how-to-sign-end-encrypt-mail-using-openssl) (deleted) and [Sec Policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69189/how-to-sign-and-encrypt-mail-using-openssl)) a while ago, I [asked about it](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/un-duplicate-my-question-that-was-posted-on-ul-security-se-sites) , and policy was [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) to cross post.

So is cross posting ...

- allowed
- frown upon
- tolerated
- forbidden
- strictly forbidden  ?

Answer (score 6):

Cross-posting is not allowed and [is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/203101). However, cross-posting only refers to posts *by the same author*. If you ask here and somebody else asks on SO, that's not cross-posting. In the example you cite, the OP here was not the same person who'd asked on SO so it's not a cross-post.

Personally, I feel that the SE community is a bit too obsessed with cross-posts and that it's a mentality left over from the days of the trilogy (SO,SF and SU) whose scopes were much clearer and with less overlap. Today we have sites like AU, U&L etc. whose scopes are very similar and it would, in my opinion, be a good idea to have a mechanism to somehow link Qs from different sites or allow cross-posting or something but I seem to be in the minority.

In any case, at the moment, community consensus is clearly against cross-posts so no, they're not allowed.

Comment: Please clarify: I recall reading the it's OK to ask a question on *one* SE site and also one or more non-SE sites.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Scott sure, non-se sites don't count. We can hardly demand that someone posts here and only here. Cross-posting only applies to multiple sites of SE

Comment: Yes! If we could flag questions for moderator to decide if the question can be displayed on two or more sites, life would be so much easier!